# netbeans tomcat jt400 link data base

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, jt400

First of all sorry for my English it's my second language.

i'm trying to move from a websphere server to a tomcat 8 server.
Every thing is working fine except for the connection with the data base.

I look on different place as far as i understand i have to modify the context.xml
but i keep getting this log form tomcat :

the first part translate to "Problem while declaring pool"

[BDD ERROR] Probl?me lors de la d?claration du pool : Cannot create resource instance

here is the context.xml and the class i use to commect withe data base.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Context path="/CGR_Server" reloadable="true">
<Resource auth="Container"
name="java:comp/env/jdbc/OLA"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
driverClassName="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionPoolDataSource"
url="jdbc:as400://OLA;naming=system;errors=full;"
username="XXXX"
password="XXXX"
maxIdle="10"
maxActive="200"
maxWait="5"
removeAbandoned="true"
removeAbandonedTimeout="1200"
/> 
</Context>
```

the method to connect to the as400

```
public boolean open(){
        DataSource source=null;                 
        try {

            source= (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup(pools[as400]);
            connection = source.getConnection();


            if (connection == null){
                return false;
            }else{

                connection.setAutoCommit(autoCommit);
                if(scroll){
                    stmt=connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                }else{
                    stmt=connection.createStatement();
                }
            }
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            traitementErreur(e);
            return false;               
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            traitementErreur(e);
            return false;           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            traitementErreur(e);
            return false;
        }

        return true;    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We use Spring and Apache DBCP2 to configure the datasource. That way it is available for tests running in JUnit without starting Tomcat, and portable to other servers as well:

```
<bean id="db2DataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver"/>
  <property name="url" value="${your.url}"/>
  <property name="username" value="${your.user}"/>
  <property name="password" value="${your.password}"/>
  <property name="connectionProperties" value="secure=${useSecureConnection};naming=system;block size=512;socket timeout=30000;date format=iso;prompt=false" />
  <property name="validationQuery" value="values 1"/>
  <property name="validationQueryTimeout" value="5"/>
</bean>
```

And then just inject the datasource into your class with Spring.